# iOS: email sending is freezing up

Tags: ios, email

I am trying to send an email with the following code — I’m not getting any errors, and the email client will load, but it won’t send the email:

```
- (IBAction)emailButtonPressed {
    MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;

NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

// Build the path to the database file
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"ral.db"]];

const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

self.html = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head></head><body>Key: <table> <tr> <td style='border: solid 1px #f75fea; text-align: center; background-color: #ed9ce6;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;X&nbsp;&nbsp;</td> </tr> </table> Start of Cycle,<table> <tr> <td style='border: solid 1px #f75fea; text-align: center;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;M&nbsp;&nbsp;</td> </tr> </table> Mild Pain, <table>  <tr> <td style='border: solid 1px #f75fea; text-align: center;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;S&nbsp;&nbsp;</td> </tr> </table> Severe Pain<br/><br/><br/><table><tr>"];

int i = 0;

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &ral) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * from DIARY order by _id"];

    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(ral, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            if ((i == 14) || (i == 28) || (i == 42) || (i == 56) || (i == 70) || (i == 84) || (i == 98) || (i == 112)) {
                [self.html appendString:@" </tr> <tr> "];
            }

            //create an image view
            NSMutableString *timeStamp = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];

            NSString *timeStamp_  = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", timeStamp] substringToIndex:5];

            NSMutableString *periodStart = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
            NSMutableString *painValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
            [self.html appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" <td> <table> <tr> <td style='font-family: arial; color:#777;'> %@ </td> </tr> ", timeStamp_]];

            [self.html appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<tr> <td style='border: solid 1px #f75fea; text-align: center; background-color: #ed9ce6; width: 20px; height: 20px;font-family: arial; color:#333;'>&nbsp;%@&nbsp;</td> </tr> ", periodStart]];

            [self.html appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<tr> <td style='border: solid 1px #f75fea; text-align: center; width: 20px; height: 20px;font-family: arial; color:#333;'>&nbsp;%@&nbsp;</td> </tr> </table> </td>", painValue]];

            i = i + 1;
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(ral);
}
[self.html appendString:@"</table></body></html>"];

NSString *tempHtml = self.html;

[controller setSubject:@"Pain diary"];
[controller setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", tempHtml] isHTML:YES];

// Show email view
Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
if (mailClass != nil) {
    // We must always check whether the current device is configured for sending emails
    if ([mailClass canSendMail]) {
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    } else {
        //do something
        NSLog(@"cant send mail");
    }
} else {
    //do something
    NSLog(@"class not instantiated");

}
}
```

Can anyone see why this is happening?

Comment: Why do you create the controller and set it all up and then check if the class exists and if the mail can be sent? If the class doesn't exist then your code will crash long before you do the check. Don't create the controller or set it up unless you know you can send the email.

Answer (score 1):

I realised I needed to capture the sending event from within my code

as such

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```